# Trouble building Dogecoind on OS X

Tags: dogecoin, daemon, compiling

I'm trying to build Dogecoind. It goes fine but I keep getting this error:

```
/Users/slayter/dogecoin/src/db.h:15:10: fatal error: 'db_cxx.h' file not found
include <db_cxx.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install BerkleyDB, refer to this document ./doc/build-osx.md